# Easiest way to print RichEditBox Document

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

UWP Windows 10. C#

What the easiest way to print RTF Document from `RichEditBox`?

I found the solution from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204545.aspx), but I don't completely understand this. In this example prints element (like `RichEditBox` screenshot). I need just to print `RichEditBox.Document` text...

Comment: No, I want to print document as RTF file

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you need is save a Rich Text Format (.rtf) file in a [RichEditBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

To do this, you can refer to the official [RichEditBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280220.aspx) document, there is sample in this document shows how to edit, load, and save a Rich Text Format (.rtf) file in a RichEditBox.